# Continuous probability question on product lifetime, with solution

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand the following continuous probability question from [this site](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_3_6_solved2.php) and solution.  I think my issue is one of understanding the wording and applying it to the solution.  Appreciate your guidance.

You purchase a certain product. The manual states that the lifetime $T$ of the product, defined as the amount of time (in years) the product works properly until it breaks down, satisfies:

$P(T \ge t) = e^{-t/5}$ for all  $t \ge 0$

For example, the probability that the product lasts more than (or equal to) 2 years is:
$P(T \ge 2) = e^{-2/5} = 0.6703$

- a) Find the probability that the product breaks down within three years of the purchase time.
- b) Find the probability that the product breaks down in the second year, i.e., find $P(1 \le T \lt 2)$

The solution to (a) is as follows...

The probability that the product breaks down within three years of the purchase time is:

$$P(T \lt 3) = 1 - P(T \ge 3) = 1 - e^{-3/5}$$

*Isn't this the probability that the product **lasts** within the first three years?  I.e. based on the definition of $T$ above?*

For (b), "the probability that the product breaks down in the second year," the solution is as follows:

$A \subset B$ then

$$P(B-A) = P(B) - P(B \cap A)= P(B) - P(A)$$

$A = [2, \infty), B = [1, \infty)$

$$P(1 \le T \lt 2) = P(T \ge 1) - P(T \ge 2)= e^{-1/5} - e^{-2/5}$$

*I have the same question as above here.  Isn't $P(1 \le T \lt 2)$ the probability $T$ lasts throughout the first year?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional probability question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167930/conditional-probability-question)

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is the random lifetime of the product.  So if $T < 3$, this means the lifetime of the product is less than $3$ years.  It could be $2$, it could be $0.0001$ years, any value less than $3$.  You can equivalently think of $T$ as the time that the product fails; i.e., it is the time when the product breaks.  Thus $\Pr[T < 3]$ is the probability that the product fails before $3$ years.

Similarly, $\Pr[1 \le T < 2]$ means that the product lasts at least one year--that's the $1 \le T$ part of the inequality--but then breaks down before $2$ years, which is the $T < 2$ part.  It simply means the failure time is at least $1$ but not more than $2$ years.